Linux Fedora 39, ошибка в работе драйверов Nvidia версии 470 и 390
Дистрибутив - Linux Fedora 39, видеокарта - nvidia gtx 765M (Вся нужная информация будет чуть ниже)
У меня проблема, что драйвер 390 не может полноценно запускать некоторые .sh скрипты (например, metro exodus) (возникает ошибка "ошибка сегментирования" и приложение падает). А драйвер версии 470 выдает ошибку на команду "DRP_PRIME=1":
glx: failed to create dri3 screen
failed to load driver: nouveau

То есть, 390 не запускает полностью все необходимые программы, а 470 отказывается запускать видеокарту для работы с программой.
Я очень долго пробовал исправить обе ошибки для двух драйверов, но ни в одном случае не нашел решения для себя. Мне нет разницы, какой драйвер оставить, мне главное - чтобы все работало стабильно.
Информация о моей системе:
inxi -G:
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915
    v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] driver: nvidia v: 470.239.06
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.20.14 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa dri: crocus
    gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 vendor: intel mesa v: 23.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel HD
    Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib
  API: EGL Message: EGL data requires eglinfo. Check --recommends.

neofetch:
OS: Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Editi 
    .:cccccccccccccccccccccccccc:.       Host: W35xSTQ_370ST 
  .;ccccccccccccc;.:dddl:.;ccccccc;.     Kernel: 6.8.7-200.fc39.x86_64 
 .:ccccccccccccc;OWMKOOXMWd;ccccccc:.    Uptime: 11 mins 
.:ccccccccccccc;KMMc;cc;xMMc:ccccccc:.   Packages: 2457 (rpm), 15 (flatpak) 
,cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cc;;WW::cccccccc,   Shell: bash 5.2.26 
:cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:ccccccc;oxOOOo;MMM0OOk.;cccccccccccc:   DE: GNOME 45.5 
cccccc:0MMKxdd:;MMMkddc.;cccccccccccc;   WM: Mutter 
ccccc:XM0';cccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc'   WM Theme: Adwaita 
ccccc;MMo;ccccc;MMW.;ccccccccccccccc;    Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
ccccc;0MNc.ccc.xMMd:ccccccccccccccc;     Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
cccccc;dNMWXXXWM0::cccccccccccccc:,      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
cccccccc;.:odl:.;cccccccccccccc:,.       CPU: Intel i7-4700MQ (8) @ 3.400GHz 
:cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc:'.         GPU: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor 
.:cccccccccccccccccccccc:;,..            GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 765M 
  '::cccccccccccccc::;,.                 Memory: 2410MiB / 11875MiB 

spci | grep NVIDIA:
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] (rev a1)

Какую информацию еще нужно добавить?

Мне нет разницы, какой драйвер оставить, мне главное - чтобы все работало стабильно - так чего вы голову себе морочите с этими блобами. используйте nouveau

@aleksandrbarakin чтобы работало стабильно медленно  (ну и вообще я сильно сомневаюсь, что metro exodus запустится на nouveau)

with: Xwayland - если сейчас в федоре действительно запущен Wayland, то в первую очередь нужно избавляться от Wayland

@andreymal, что значит медленно??? игрушки тормозят? так для игрушек есть специальная операционная система - ms/windows.

@aleksandrbarakin с nouveau тоже не работает. Не получается запускать программы через дискрет (DRP_PRIME=1 не выдает ошибок, но и ничего не меняет в работе программ)

Что такое DRP_PRIME и почему вы решили, что оно должно что-то менять?

@andreymal оно не должно что-то менять, оно должно указывать системе, что данную программу нужно запускать с использованием дискретной видеокарты

Почему вы решили, что оно должно что-то кому-то указывать?
